# Trouble with Haskell filtering a list in a different type (Int and Float)

Tags: haskell

Can someone help me out why this code doesnt want to work? I am new to Haskell and I have no clue.

```
int2Float :: Int -> Float
int2Float x = fromIntegral x :: Float

isbigCircle :: Float -> Int -> Bool
isbigCircle y x = (int2Float x)^2*pi > y

bigCircles :: Float -> [Int] -> [Float]
bigCircles y list = filter (isbigCircle y) list
```

Comment: if you filter a list of `Int`s you will get back a list of `Int`s, not `Float`s. You can always use `fromIntegral` (or your `int2Float`, which is just a restricted version) again if you really need need a list of Floats.

Comment: PS it's rare in Haskell to use `Float` instead of `Double` and I'm not sure there's any advantage. `Double` is more accurate, and while it does take more space I'm sure I read somewhere that because it's the most common it's actually optimised to perform better than `Float`!

Comment: @RobinZigmond Agreed Float is unusual, but surely it is not without advantage. It could be smaller than Double, and it is required when conforming to some spec that mandates single-precision floats, or interoperating with an FFI library that wants a float.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Thank you so much! I forgot to change that... all the logic was good at least... I was testing with both so I could make it work and that was an assignment (along with some other stuff I  had no problem with) so I will not change the list type. By the way if you want to send a proper answer I will accept it.

Comment: @RobinZigmond the main reason `Float` doesn't make sense in Haskell is that it takes up _the same_ amount of space in practice. Both `Float` and `Double` are actually a 64-bit pointer to a 64-bit-aligned memory location. However, that doesn't apply when storing them in unboxed vectors, in which case `Float` can indeed make a lot of sense. And, yes, `Float` can actually be faster on modern processors because you can make more use of SIMD vectorisation – though that's something GHC still doesn't, really, do.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, filtering a list of `Int`s will result in a list of `Int`s. A better way to approach this would be

```hs
isBigCircle :: Float -> Float -> Bool
isBigCircle y x = x^2 * pi > y

bigCirclesFloat :: Float -> [Float] -> [Float]
bigCirclesFloat y = filter $ isBigCircle y

bigCirclesInt :: Float -> [Int] -> [Float]
bigCirclesInt float = bigCirclesFloat y . fmap fromIntegral
```